# How do I query a table?

Tags: wpdb

I am using Contact form 7 and the database extension, the db extension creates a table called wp_CF7DBPlugin_SUBMITS. I have 2 forms on my site, I need to know if the user has completed the 2nd form, so when they return they can skip the 1st form.

I don't even know where to start with this, any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: It would help if you could add sample row from table with data you want to get out of it.

Answer (score 1):

Codex has extensive [`wpdb`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#SELECT_Generic_Results) reference on how to perform different kinds of requests to database. However in most cases it is best to try to access data with available WP or theme/plugin code first.